# Tables are deleted on ejabberd server automatically

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, mnesia

I wrote a module on ejabberd server which creates four new tables on ejabberd.

And i configured this module on port number 5280 on ejabberd(On this PORT http request is handled i.e ejabberd_http module is configured here but with tls off).

Then i triggered the module via with command-> curl

http://ip_adddress:port_no/url_configured_on_ejabberd.

It successfully created the tables.Similary i have configured some modules on 5290(ejabberd_http module is configured here too but with tls on).Now when i open ejabberd GUI via port 5280(http://IP:5280/admin/node/ejabberd@localhost/db/)

it shows all tables.

But when i open ejabberd via(https://IP:5290/admin/node/ejabberd@localhost/db/) my all four tables are deleted every time.

Is there any issues regarding the server to help me solve the issue ?

Comment: why are you taking from 5290 port?

Comment: tried with other ports ?

Comment: How do you create the table ? Is that Mnesia table ? Are you sure it is not in-memory only ? You should show the code you used to create table.